# keyboard layout EN after boot

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout

I can't believe this bug has still not been solved with Ubuntu 14.04 ?
On my 2 laptops, Acer and Asus, on a random basis, the keyboard layout switch from FR to EN.

This is very frustrating when you type a password and can't see the letters.

How to solve that for good ?

Comment: Are you using auto-login?

Comment: No autologin.strange, bug hasn't appeared for 1 week, perhaps due to last updates ?

Comment: spoke to fast, bug is back today !!!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Trashing the file in `/home/user/.config/ibus` solved the issue.

Comment: Can you explain better? "Trashing the file", what file?

Comment: Trash the entire ibus folder and relogin.

Comment: does not work for me!

Answer (score 6):

This should fix the problem in 13.10 and 14.04:

In the ubuntu software center, install "dconf Editor" (`dconf-editor`) (if you don't already have it). Open it, then open desktop -> ibus -> general. Now enable the property "use-system-keyboard-layout". (You want it to have a checkmark next to it.)

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1240198

Comment: It was there, but still didn't work...

Answer (score 2):

Run command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
```

Now use the Keyboard Icon to reset to whatever it should be - viz the diagram.

[image]

Comment: unfortunatelly, bug is still here at random !

Answer (score 0):

I found at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1376466 the solution.
It appears that there is a issue in defining the keyboard layout when the UID of the user is 1000.

You must logout of your current session and login as root (if you didn't previously, before logout set a root password by running in terminal `sudo passwd root` and follow the steps).

At login screen hit on the keyboard CTRL + ALT + F1.

Do login as root.
Type `usermod -u 1001 your_user_name`. 1001 is just a suggestion, you can put another.
Then reboot by typing `reboot`.

Hope it works!

Comment: Impossible to login as root, password rejected !!!even if i've just changed the password. I tried 2 times.

Comment: login incorrect what should I enter as login ?

Comment: Try to login as usual, then open Terminal and try get root running  `sudo su`.

Comment: terminal return ***user ... is currently used by process 1611***

Comment: Is that when you try to run usermod? Can you get su running `sudo su` in Terminal? If so, try to set the root password typing `passwd`. Then try that step at login screen again. Sorry if im being redundant, I don't know exactly the steps you took.

Comment: That's what I get when logging as usual         >      fred@fred-X201EP:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for fred: 
root@fred-X201EP:/home/fred# usermod -u 1001 fred
usermod: user fred is currently used by process 1724***

Answer (score -2):

Just run the following command line in a terminal and configure your keyboard layout correctly:

```
sudo ibus-setup
```

then reboot and enjoy. :)

Comment: doesn't work, still EN at reboot at random even if EN is not in the layout menu !!!

Answer (score -2):

Just type:

```
setxkbmap fr
```

on a terminal.

I tried it on Raspberry Pi, Debian, Ubuntu and Fedora.

Comment: doesn't work stil EN at reboot!

Comment: Thanks, at least I can write characters like "-" now... damn Ubuntu Unity GUI, can't even set Keyboard-Layout in Keyboard Menu.